# Is it ok to put business logic into a saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm developing a small react/redux/saga application. It is basically a multistep form with `Back` and `Next` buttons, and a progress bar. Each form step (or form screen) has a number of fields.

According to spec, the form should be able to store the user entered data on server step-by-step – i.e., upon each click on the `Next` button. This button acts like a typical `submit` button for the current form step, but it should also take the user further if all requests are successful. If the server returns an error for at least one field on the current step, the user should not have the possibility to progress to the next one.

The catch is that requests to the server are not predetermined – some entities may be modified, some – added, and some – deleted. This all depends on the user choices.
So, technically, before letting the user move to the next step, I must ensure that only needed requests were sent to the server, and, of course, that the server responded with success statuses to those requests.

I'm using redux-saga to manage side effects, and I just don't see how I can make individual requests (like addUserEducation, deleteUserEducation, etc.) from within the component itself and still meet the spec. It feels like this specific case forces me to put a significant part of my "business" logic into a saga that takes all data from the form screen and use it to decide on what should be sent to the server. Since I use a blocking call for each request, I can, hopefully, rely on the error selector in the end of the saga to take (or not to take) the user to the next step conditionally.

This approach works but I`m not sure if it agrees with redux-saga best practises because a number of my sagas become too "fat" and not strictly doing only side effects stuff. I think it may be suboptimal and there should be more elegant alternatives to solve this problem. Please help!

```js
// Education.js (one of the form screens)

const sendForms = (nextStep, history) => {
    handleEducation(
      { userId, educationList, forms, formList },
      nextStep,
      history,
    );
  };
```

```js
// userSagas.js

function* handleEducation({ payload }) {
  try {
    const {
      screenData: { userId, educationList, forms, formList },
      nextStep,
      history,
    } = payload;

    // Collect ids of the forms that were `dropped` by the user,..
    const formsToDelete = educationList.reduce((acc, edObj) => {
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(forms, edObj.id)) {
        return [...acc, edObj.id];
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    // ...and delete the corresponding educations on server.
    yield all(
      formsToDelete.map(educationId =>
        call(deleteUserEducation, userId, educationId),
      ),
    );

    // Handle forms that are still present.
    yield all(
      formList.map(([educationId, form], index) => {
        const { school, startYear, endYear, toDate } = form;
        let fields = {
          institution: school,
          enrolled_on: startYear,
          graduated_on: endYear,
          is_current: toDate,
        };

        const isLast = index + 1 === formList.length;

        if (educationId.includes('new')) {
          // Add new education
          if (isLast && toDate === true) {
            // Omit `graduated_on` field
            const { graduated_on: graduatedOn, ...withoutGraduated } = fields;
            fields = withoutGraduated;

            return call(addUserEducation, userId, fields);
          }
          return call(addUserEducation, userId, fields);
        }

// ...more code here...

    const errors = yield select(userSelectors.selectErrors);

    if (!errors) {
      history.push(steps[nextStep].route);
    }
  } catch (er) {
    const { response } = er;

    console.log('errors: ', response.data);
  }
}
```